# sed to change userid in /etc/passwd to zero

Tags: sed, passwd, uid

I am trying to change user monitor  uid in /etc/passwd , but below gives me an error:

```
sed -s /etc/passwd <<-"EOF"
        /^\(monitor:[^:]*:\)[0-9]*:[0-9]*:/s//\10:0:/
        w
        q
EOF
```

Comment: ... This sounds like a tremendously bad idea if you accidentally succeed. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use usermod -u. That's what it is there for

Comment: You're confusing `sed` with `ed`

Comment: I need to change userid to zero, can't use usermode.

Comment: Why do you "need" to change userid to 0? I bet if you explained the problem you are really trying to solve, somebody would come up with a better idea of how to solve it.

Comment: I am using proprietary RHEL5 like hardened system where I added user as admin with uid 0. After reboot uid is  changed backed to non-zero

Comment: How have you added the user to the admin group? With groupmod?

Comment: Perhaps the UID of a non-root user being changed _from_ zero is part of the aforementioned hardening because, as also previously mentioned, this is a terrible idea which is bad and implementing it should make you feel bad.  Why do you think this is a necessary thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason `usermod -u` can not be used:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\(monitor:[^:]\):[0-9]*:[0-9]*:/\1:0:0:/' /etc/passwd
```

Please note it is `/\1:0` not `/\10:` as this would be parameter 10.

But having `monitor` to have uid 0 might not be a good idea at all.